# How to switch python print results to string instead of object?

Tags: python, string, twilio, gspread

I'm working on a tool that will send bulk SMS text messages.  I am using the Twilio API - I have two lists in a Google Sheet, one that is phone numbers, one that is first names.

My script loops through the lists, assigns the name as a variable, then creates the messages.

When I reference the lists from the Google Sheet, I'm running into an error - I think based on how the info is printing.

Here's the overview:

**WORKING SCRIPT NOT USING GOOGLE SHEETS LIST - THIS PRINTS PERFECTLY:**

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import gspread

# Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
account_sid = '#################'
auth_token = '#################'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')

# Open a spreadsheet by ID
sh = gc.open_by_key('1KRYITQ_O_-7exPZp8zj1VvAUPPutqtO4SrTgloCx8x4')

# Get the sheets
wk = sh.worksheet("Numbers to Send")

# E.G. the URLs are listed on Sheet 1 on Column A
# numbers = wk.batch_get(('E3:E',))[0]
# names = wk.batch_get(('D3:D',))[0]

names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Jim']
numbers = ['+PhoneNumber', '+PhoneNumber', '+PhoneNumber']

# Loop through the names and numbers and send a text message to each phone number
for i in range(len(names)):
    message = client.messages.create(
        to=numbers[i],
        from_='+18442251378',
        body=f"Hello {names[i]}, this is a test message from Twilio.")
    print(f"Message sent to {names[i]} at {numbers[i]}")
```

However, when I try to get the lists from the Google Sheet, the message prints like this:

"Hello ['Zak'], this is a message from Twilio"... whereas the first method (not using Sheets), does not place the brackets around the name.  It sends like a clean string.

I tried adding in a str pre-fix on the names variable, but it didn't work.  Any ideas how I could tweak this into printing a clean message?

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import gspread

# Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
account_sid = '#####################'
auth_token = '######################'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')

# Open a spreadsheet by ID
sh = gc.open_by_key('1KRYITQ_O_-7exPZp8zj1VvAUPPutqtO4SrTgloCx8x4')

# Get the sheets
wk = sh.worksheet("Numbers to Send")

# E.G. the URLs are listed on Sheet 1 on Column A
numbers = wk.batch_get(('E3:E',))[0]
names = wk.batch_get(('D3:D',))[0]

# names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Jim']
# numbers = ['+16099725052', '+16099725052', '+16099725052']

# Loop through the names and numbers and send a text message to each phone number
for i in range(len(names)):
    message = client.messages.create(
        to=numbers[i],
        from_='+18442251378',
        body=f"Hello {names[i]}, this is a test message from Twilio.")
    print(f"Message sent to {names[i]} at {numbers[i]}")
```

Comment: If `names[i]` is `['Zak']`, then `names` must be a nested list, not a plain list as in your first code example.  Try `names[i][0]`.

Comment: @john gordon--can you make this an answer so it can be marked as answer?

Comment: @lizziepika It seems like this was a simple typo or misunderstanding.  I didn't think such questions were supposed to receive formal answers.